# JSTL error in freemarker template

Tags: jstl, freemarker

I am trying to implement JSTL in Freemarker template. To do that, I got a sample freemarker template example and tried to incorporate JSTL namespace and trying to execute it. 
Here is how my code looks right now.

```
<html>
<head><title>ViralPatel.net - FreeMarker Spring MVC Hello World</title>
<#assign c=JspTaglibs["http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"]/>
<style>
body, input {
font-family: Calibri, Arial;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
#header h2 {
color: white;
background-color: #3275A8;
height: 50px;
padding: 5px 0 0 5px;
font-size: 20px;
}

.datatable {margin-bottom:5px;border:1px solid #eee;border-      collapse:collapse;width:400px;max-width:100%;font-family:Calibri}
.datatable th {padding:3px;border:1px solid #888;height:30px;background-color:#B2D487;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;color:#444444}
.datatable tr {border:1px solid #888}
.datatable tr.odd {background-color:#eee}
.datatable td {padding:2px;border:1px solid #888}
#content { padding 5px; margin: 5px; text-align: center}

fieldset { width: 300px; padding: 5px; margin-bottom: 0px; }
legend { font-weight: bold; }
</style>

<body>
<div id="header">
<H2>
<a href="http://viralpatel.net"><img height="37" width="236" border="0px" src="http://viralpatel.net/blogs/wp-content/themes/vp/images/logo.png" align="left"/></a>
FreeMarker Spring MVC Hello World
</H2>
 </div>

<div id="content">
<c:set var="Salary" value="4000/>
<c:out value="${Salary}/>

 <fieldset>
<legend>Add User</legend>
 <form name="user" action="add.html" method="post">
Firstname: <input type="text" name="firstname" />   <br/>
Lastname: <input type="text" name="lastname" /> <br/>


<input type="submit" value="   Save   " />
  </form>
  </fieldset>
  <br/>
  <table class="datatable">
<tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>  <th>Lastname</th>
</tr>
    <#list model["userList"] as user>
<tr>
    <td>${user.firstname}</td> <td>${user.lastname}</td>
</tr>
    </#list>

  </table>

</div>  
 </body>
</html>
```

I know the problem is with the new code I added  i.e Salary and I see the following error.

```
freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: Expression Salary is undefined on line 62, column 5 in index.ftl.
at freemarker.core.TemplateObject.assertNonNull(TemplateObject.java:124)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks
Nikhil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is not understanding how Freemarker works and thinking that it's somehow completely inoperable with JSP.  As far as I can tell, you have imported JSTL in order to set and output variable values when Freemarker already does this.

Replace this:

```
<c:set var="Salary" value="4000/>
<c:out value="${Salary}/>
```

...with this:

```
<#assign Salary = 4000>
${Salary}
```

Also, rid yourself of the JSTL taglib and just learn how to use Freemarker.  You will be much happier.

Comment: Something my manager asked to find out if I could do it or not. So Started messing with it. looks like I have to get it into her head about the use of FTL :)

Comment: It's really much simpler than JSP.  I hope you think so, too.  Good luck with your research.

Comment: jsp + jstl is easier for me rather then using freemarker. it covers all that i need. but if you have to work with freemarker, you work with it and you can't use jstl ;)